# ios coredata fetch elements of a specific parent

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an app using coreData fine.

I have this relationship:

company <--->> visitors

now, I need to find specific visitors for an specific company, I can fetch visitors starting with some string pattern,

But how to find the ones for a specific company?

here my code

```
- (void)searchAvailableDataFullName:(NSTimer*)timer
 {

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName BEGINSWITH [c] %@",self.nameTF.text];  

//sort descriptor! 

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

//the relationship of interest??
Visitor *theVisitor = nil;
theVisitor.company = self.selectedCompany;

NSMutableArray *fullNamesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Visitor allWithPredicate:predicate sortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]]];


Visitor *visitorName;

NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (visitorName in fullNamesArray) {
    NSLog(@"tus visitors:: %@", visitorName.fullName);

    [dataArray addObject:visitorName.fullName];

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my Mac in front of me atm but it should be something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"visitors.fullName BEGINSWITH [c] %@ && visitors.CompanyName BEGINSWITH [c] %@",self.nameTF.text, companyNameTextObject];
```

Hope that's 100% right, if not you can kind of get the gist of it. You can use the "table.relationshipProperty" to search the relationship.

[Apple Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

There's some more info there, just check out the "Joins" section. Hope that helps!